# postgres coldfusion concatenation of string inside cfquery tag

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, postgresql-9.1

```
<cfquery name="LOCAL.qrySelEvents" datasource="#variables.datasourceSettings.getDatasourceName()#" result="LOCAL.qryData" >
    SELECT evt_id, 
           acnt_dba_name,
           form_id,
           '#application.portals.data[request.applicationName].profileRootPath#form/index.cfm' 
               || CHAR(63) 
               || 'PKformID= ' 
               || #preserveSingleQuotes(LOCAL.formIdSql)# AS primaryFormURL,
    FROM    events
</cfquery>
```

I have to concat #application.portals.data[request.applicationName].profileRootPath#form/index.cfm with char(32) and PKformID= ' || #preserveSingleQuotes(LOCAL.formIdSql)#. I have used the `||` operator of postgres. But it is giving me an error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "||"

Can you please help me in this?

Comment: I am very new to cold fusion , please help me in this.

Comment: As an aside `preserveSingleQuotes` is generally avoided because it opens a database to sql injection if the input was not properly scrubbed.

Answer (score 3):

The last line of your select clause has a comma at the end.

Answer (score 1):

OK, as well as the error message, if you have `ROBUST EXCEPTION HANDLING` switched on (it's in CFAdmin), you should get back the SQL that CF was passing to the server. This should show you where the syntax error is in your SQL.  You should also always post this info in your question, so even if you can't see the problem, someone else might be able to.

Now I *suspect* it's because this:

```
#preserveSingleQuotes(LOCAL.formIdSql)#
```

needs to be treated as a string (which it is), in which case you'll need to quote it for the DB to see it as a string. IE:

```
'#preserveSingleQuotes(LOCAL.formIdSql)#'
```

Given there is no DB-centric references in that whole value:

```
`'#application.portals.data[request.applicationName].profileRootPath#form/index.cfm' || CHAR(63) || 'PKformID= ' || '#preserveSingleQuotes(LOCAL.formIdSql)#'`
```

I question why you need to include it in your SELECT query. You're basically just passing the value to the SQL server, and just getting it back again afterwards. So I suspect something is amiss here. What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Ya finally got the answer of this , CHAR(63) is creating problem in this as in Sql-server CHAR is a function which gives Character from ASCII and in postgresql CHR() function is available in order to give  character from ASCII. So , new Query is :

```
<cfquery name="LOCAL.qrySelEvents" datasource="#variables.datasourceSettings.getDatasourceName()#" result="LOCAL.qryData" >
    SELECT evt_id, 
           acnt_dba_name,
           form_id,
           '#application.portals.data[request.applicationName].profileRootPath#form/index.cfm' 
               || CHR(63) 
               || 'PKformID= ' 
               || #preserveSingleQuotes(LOCAL.formIdSql)# AS primaryFormURL
    FROM    events
</cfquery>
```

Thanks for all your support.